# How to enable google apps users to edit theirs profile and share it with Google Apps Directory

Tags: google-workspace, google-contacts

At our company we use Google Apps. We want to list all accounts as a contacts and allow people to edit theirs contact profile, so others can use theirs updated profiles.

Google provides *Google Apps Directory*. But users can't edit it.

How to allow users to share theirs profile in some common directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it directly. Only via API within Google services.

However, there are tools. The tool we have used is FlashPanel. You can get it in the Google Apps Marketplace.

Right now it is completely free. It is my understanding they are planning to make a free and paid version.